# use another workspace in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The equivalent expression for '**./**' as a path in Jenkins.

I want to use the workspace of another job and I need the equivalent expression for '**./**' for the workspace of the other job.

So I can access the folders in the workspace.

Comment: "Another job" is not guaranteed to be there, to run on the same node, or to run ever. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I generated files in another job. They are in a folder in the workspace of the other job. Now I want to access these files in my current pipeline, but they are not in the workspace.

Comment: The way to address it is that the first job will "archive artifacts" (the generated files).  You can then use Jenkins API to access these artifacts. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39960198/2047614 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36843215/2047614

Comment: thank you. But how can i get a specific folder ?